# Unable to set default boolean parameter to a default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been reading about ways to set default parameters for jQuery functions. I like creating a JSON object within the function and using extend to merge any passed options. But for now I have a function that is defined as follows:

```
function SetGroup( convert ) { 
    convert = convert || true;
    ....
})
```

The value of convert is always getting set to true. Calling SetGroup() in all of the following ways results in convert == true:

```
SetGroup();
SetGroup(true);
SetGroup(false);
```

I have another parameter that I set the default value for like this and it works, but it's also a string. I suspect the problem above is due to the parameter being a boolean?

How do I make this work for a boolean param?

Answer (score 4):

The `variable = variable || true` syntax for defaulting a variable to true relies on the first parameter being "falsey" in the JS sense. This means that any value of `variable` which evaluates to false in a boolean expression will be overwritten with the value `true`.

Like you mentioned, this works wonderfully when the defined value is not naturally "falsey" (e.g. with a string or a non-zero integer). However, this doesn't work for booleans. As you might guess, `false` is in fact "falsey".

By definition, the boolean OR operator `||` returns the right operand if the left one is falsey. So it will always return true if the left operand is always a boolean, and the right one is always `true`.

Instead, try this:

```
function setGroup( convert ) { 
    convert = (convert != false);
    ....
})
```

If `convert` is `undefined`, it'll be `true`. Likewise if it's `true`. If `convert` is `false`, it remains `false`.